# Operator overloading of struct inside another struct gives error

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

```
struct MyStruct {
  struct Node {
    int a;
  };
  Node operator + (const Node &A, const Node &B) {
    Node ret;
    ret.a = A.a + B.a;
    return ret;
  };
};
```

The above code gives error:
 `‘MyStruct::Node MyStruct::operator+(const MyStruct::Node&, const MyStruct::Node&)’ must take either zero or one argument`.

While the following codes compiles correctly -

```
struct Node {
  int a;
};
Node operator + (const Node &A, const Node &B) {
  Node ret;
  ret.a = A.a + B.a;
  return ret;
};
```

and

```
struct MyStruct {
  struct Node {
    int a;
    Node operator + (const Node &B) {
      a += B.a;
      return *this;
    };
  };
};
```

How can I overload operator of `Node` outside the `Node` structure but inside `MyStruct`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I overload operator of Node outside the Node structure but inside MyStruct?

You can't do that. Any overload operators defined outside `Node` and inside `MyStruct` is treated as an overload operator of `MyStruct`. This is where a `namespace` is different from a `struct`.

You can use:

```
struct MyStruct {
  struct Node {
    int a;
  };
};

MyStruct::Node operator+(MyStruct::Node const& A, MyStruct::Node const& B) {
   MyStruct::Node ret;
   ret.a = A.a + B.a;
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I think `Node ret` also needs to be changed to `MyStruct::Node ret`.

Comment: But is there no way I could do it _inside_ MyStruct, as stated in question? Edit: answer updated.